# Select2 makes an ajax call each time I open it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to populate a select2 control only when users open it, but it makes lots of ajax call, and for lots of ajax calls I mean it continue sending post request, also I can't event close the select2, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
 $('#select').select2().one('select2-open', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/url',
    data: {
        data: data
    },
    type: "POST"
}).done(function (data) {
    var optionhtml = "<option value=''></option>";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        optionhtml += "<option value='" + data[i].field_id + "'>" + data[i].field + "</option>";
    }
    $("#select").html(optionhtml);
    $("#select").select2({
        allowClear: true
    });
    $("#select").select2('open');
});
```

});

Comment: Well, you're calling ajax everytime you open it.. Why don't you populate the options BEFORE initialising the select ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well, I know that but when I open the select2 it doesn't make only one call it continue sending post request and after that I can't even close it.

Comment: Your ajax call is inside an open event and at the very end of everything you have `$("#select").select2('open');` which is an open command which then triggers the ajax request which then gets the data which then calls the open request that you have at the end which then triggers the ajax request ... and so on ...

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax Their documentation is excellent to be honest.

Comment: Pogrindis, and should I reinitialize the select2 every time the user open it?

Comment: @DonDev no, why would you want to do that ?

Comment: That's what I understand, sorry.

Comment: Unless you have dynamic options which can change at any time, you then would have a call everytime it's opened to ensure you're getting latest list. Otherwise just populate on init.. As demonstrated : https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Comment: It's correct data can change as it depends on previous control values.

Comment: The problem is that as parameters can change, I need to load new data to the select2 when user open it, can't figure out how, and the way the documentation says if for newer versions and I'm using version 3.5 and can't change for the moment.